# Get a legend show subscripted, italicized letters in parentheses in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how I can get my legend show the word `"Mode"['(d)']` **read**: "**Mode sub (*d*)**" in my plot in R (**Note:** **d** is ***italicized***)?

Or shown as:

[image]

**Here is the R code I have tried with no success:**

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", bty="n")

legend("top", legend=paste("Mode"['(d)'], "= ", round(.333333, 3)), 
   bty="n", inset=c(0, .01), text.font=2, cex = 1.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expression` will let you do both subscripts and italics.

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", bty="n")
legend("top", legend=expression(Mode[(italic(d))]),
   bty="n", inset=c(0, .01), text.font=2, cex = 1.5)
```

Edit: 
Looking back at your code, I think that maybe you did not want just the Mode[d] but really wanted Mode[d] = 0.333.  To get that,  use `bquote`.

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", bty="n")
legend("top", legend=bquote(Mode[(italic(d))] == .(round(.333333, 3))), 
   bty="n", inset=c(0, .01), text.font=2, cex = 1.5)
```

[image: Legend with italic subscript]

Comment: Yes.  If you want "Mode" to be in italics too, just change the legend part to `bquote(italic(Mode)[(italic(d))] == .(round(.333333, 3)))`

Comment: It appears that `bold` does not work on the math expressions - at least I don't see how to get it to do so.

Comment: Well, you don't get _much_ control.  AFAIK, you can't make it smaller, but if you want to increase the distance, you can just insert some blank spaces which you can insert by adding `~`  (tilde) wherever you want a blank.